# why my datasets are not opening in weka 3.9.6

Tags: dataset, weka

I am a ubuntu user and I am getting an error while opening ".csv" file in weka. Only the IRISH.csv file is opening but not others.I am getting this two types of error [It is the first one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eq53.png) [it is the second one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVQbj.png).

I find nothing.I just wanted to open the datasets and explore them.

Answer (score 0):

Weka's [CSVLoader](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/core/converters/CSVLoader.html) deviates from other tools that load CSV files and is sensitive to correct quoting of cells, escaping of various characters and can't handle multi-line cells.

When Weka's CSVLoader reads a CSV file, it uses the header row to determine how many columns are to be expected. If on subsequent rows, the splitting into cells results in more than the expected number of columns (e.g., due to incorrectly escaped/quoted characters), then this is the error message that you see.

Install the (unofficial) Weka package [common-csv](https://github.com/fracpete/common-csv-weka-package), which handles common CSV dialects. After restarting Weka, try loading your CSV file using the type `Common CSV files (*.csv)` rather then Weka one (`CSV data files`). If necessary, tweak the loader's parameters by checking `Invoke options dialog` in the *Open file* dialog.